# Multiple regression with every predictor interacted with a dichotomous variable, vs separate models

Tags: regression, interaction, standard-error

Consider a regression analysis with a continuous outcome, two dichotomous predictors, and their interaction. We can use R's built-in `CO2` dataset, in which plants are Quebec-type or Mississippi-type and the treatment is chilled vs not chilled.

```
summary(lm(uptake ~ Treatment * Type, data=CO2))

# Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)                        35.333      1.747  20.225  < 2e-16 ***
# Treatmentchilled                   -3.581      2.471  -1.449 0.151141    
# TypeMississippi                    -9.381      2.471  -3.797 0.000284 ***
# Treatmentchilled:TypeMississippi   -6.557      3.494  -1.877 0.064213 .
```

It seems to me that this is essentially estimating two separate models for the two plant types (or, equivalently, for the two treatment types). For a Quebec-type plant (the reference class), the intercept is `Intercept` and the effect of chilled treatment is `Treatmentchilled`. For a Mississippi-type plant, the intercept is `(Intercept + TypeMississippi)` and the effect of chilled treatment is `(Treatmentchilled + Treatmentchilled:TypeMississippi)`.

If we run a regression just for plants of the reference class:

```
summary(lm(uptake ~ Treatment, data=CO2 %>% filter(Type=="Quebec")))

#                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)        35.333      2.099  16.830   <2e-16 ***
# Treatmentchilled   -3.581      2.969  -1.206    0.235    
# F=1.455 (1,40), p=.23
```

The coefficient estimates are indeed the same, but the standard errors are larger. Why is this? Where is the additional information coming from in the multiple regression model? It's hard for me to understand how Mississippi-type plants improve the precision of parameter estimates for Quebec-type plants, while the Mississippi-type plants are also being used to estimate parameters that apply only to their own type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the expression for the variance of the regression coefficients is $$
\hat\Sigma = {\hat\sigma}^2(X'X)^{-1}
$$

The estimate of the residual variance $\hat\sigma^2$ will be different in the full model, where it is assumed to be equal among the groups, from the subgroup models, in which it is allowed to vary. If the assumption of homoscedasticty is true and the residual variance is the same in each group, then the full model will yield a more accurate estimate of the residual variance and therefore of the standard errors. If not, though, then you will see substantial differences between the residual variance of the full model and those of the subgroups, leading to different standard errors across the parameterizations.

A solution to this is to use robust standard errors, which are consistent even in the case of unequal residual variance across groups. See below (some output abridged):

```r
library(estimatr)
summary(lm_robust(uptake ~ Treatment * Type, data=CO2))
#> Standard error type:  HC2 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|) CI Lower
#> (Intercept)                        35.333      2.094  16.873 4.445e-28   31.166
#> Treatmentchilled                   -3.581      2.969  -1.206 2.313e-01   -9.489
#> TypeMississippi                    -9.381      2.645  -3.547 6.548e-04  -14.644
#> Treatmentchilled:TypeMississippi   -6.557      3.494  -1.877 6.421e-02  -13.511

summary(lm_robust(uptake ~ Treatment, data=CO2 |> subset(Type=="Quebec")))
#> Standard error type:  HC2 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper DF
#> (Intercept)        35.333      2.094  16.873 8.651e-20   31.101    39.57 40
#> Treatmentchilled   -3.581      2.969  -1.206 2.349e-01   -9.582     2.42 40
```

When using a robust standard error, the standard errors are the same. Note that the p-values will still differ because the tests use different degrees of freedom. The full model, the df are larger.